# Is there any way to pre buffer a list of videos in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-video-player

Currently I am working on a application like snapchat and tik-tok and I need to pre buffer videos or store them in cache memory before playing and play them from cache memory

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score -2):

Use precache() method to pre-load the videos before rendering the screen.

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  precacheImage(theImage.image, context);
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

Or use `precacheImage(videoName, context);` before returning Widget in build method.

Comment: i'm asking about pre caching videos not image read the question again

Comment: and what is precache() method will you please explain